How do you control alignment of elements in TradingView's settings menu using PineScript5?
I'm putting together a fib retracement indicator, I defined a bunch of inputs and grouped them up side by side by using inline
// User inputs for HIGH line properties
lineColorHigh = input(color.gray, title="Top Line Color", inline="top", group="Fibonacci Settings")
lineHighWidth = input(2, title="Top Line Width", inline="top", group="Fibonacci Settings")


// User inputs for the 78.6% Fibonacci level line properties
seventyEightSixLineColor = input.color(color.rgb(100, 181, 246), title="78.6% Line Color", inline="78.6%", group="Fibonacci Settings")
seventyEightSixLineWidth = input.int(2, title="78.6% Line Width", inline="78.6%", group="Fibonacci Settings")


// User inputs for the 61.8% Fibonacci level line properties
sixtyOneEightLineColor = input(color.yellow, title="61.8% Line Color", inline="61.8%", group="Fibonacci Settings")
sixtyOneEightLineWidth = input(2, title="61.8% Line Width", inline="61.8%", group="Fibonacci Settings")

However in the settings menu the items are not neatly aligned

Does anyone know how to fix the alignment problems?

You need to add Unicode white space characters to move forward the text. You can use the Em space ( ): 8195 (0x2003)
Here is useful F.A.Q. for you.
lineColorHigh = input(color.gray, title="Top Line Color ", inline="top", group="Fibonacci Settings")
lineHighWidth = input(2, title="Top Line Width ", inline="top", group="Fibonacci Settings")

// User inputs for the 78.6% Fibonacci level line properties
seventyEightSixLineColor = input.color(color.rgb(100, 181, 246), title="78.6% Line Color", inline="78.6%", group="Fibonacci Settings")
seventyEightSixLineWidth = input.int(2, title="78.6% Line Width", inline="78.6%", group="Fibonacci Settings")



Thanks for the link as well grateful for the resource <3
